# How to prove the multiples of $3 $ is denumerable?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Prove that the following set is denumerable.

> $T$, the integer multiples of $3$.

A denumerable set is that the set is equivalent to the set of natural numbers.

Some of the multiples of 3 include

$T = \{...,-3,0,3,6,9,12,...\}$

One must also consider the negative and positive integers multiples of 3. My question is how does one prove that this is one to one or that it is a bijection and onto?

So we know the $\Bbb Z \rightarrow T \rightarrow \Bbb N ,\text{ such that }. $ $f(z) =3z$

Then $f(x) = f(y) \Rightarrow 3x=3y \Rightarrow, x=y$, thus we can say it is one to one.   So by saying this can this be enough to say it is denumerable?

Comment: I suggest first finding a bijection between $T$ and $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: The property of being "one to one", "onto", or "bijective" belongs to a *function* between two sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to prove X is denumerable.

1) Prove there is a bijection $\phi:X \rightarrow \mathbb N $.

Or

2) Take an Y that you know is denumerable and show there is a bijection $\rho:X\rightarrow Y $.  If need be you can show $\rho\circ\phi\rightarrow \mathbb N$ is bijection.

So....

We know $\mathbb Z $ is denumerable and if we bang our heads against a wall we'll remember the bijection was $\phi:\mathbb N\rightarrow \mathbb Z::2n+1\rightarrow n $ for odd naturals; $2n\rightarrow -n $ for even so {1,2,3,4,5,6,....} $\rightarrow ${0,-1,1,-2,2,-3...}.

Finding the bijection $\rho: \mathbb Z\rightarrow 3\mathbb Z$ is incredibly obvious.  $\rho:z\rightarrow 3*z $.  So the multiples of 3 and the integers are obviously 1-1.

Proof: if $\rho (x)=\rho (y)\implies 3x=3y\implies x=y $ so $\rho $ is injective.  If $x=3n\in 3\mathbb Z $ then $\rho (n)=3n=x $ so $\rho $ is surjective.

So $\mathbb N \leftarrow\rightarrow \mathbb Z \leftarrow\rightarrow 3\mathbb Z $.

If we want the *exact* bijection it is $\rho\circ\phi: 2n+1\rightarrow n\rightarrow 3n $; $2n\rightarrow -n\rightarrow -3n $.

I.e.  {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9....} maps to {0,-3,3,-6,6,-9,9,-12,12......}.

Answer (score 1):

If you know that $\mathbb{Z}$ is enumerable, then there is an easy bijection from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $T$ sending $n \mapsto 3n$. This is easy to verify as a bijection.

If you are only using the fact that $\mathbb{N}$ is countable, then there is an easy map onto $\mathbb{N}$. If $x \in T$ is non-negative, send $x \mapsto 2^{x}$. Otherwise, send $x \mapsto 3^{-x}$. As prime factorization is unique, this is a bijection (which I leave to you to verify).

> > My question is how does one prove that this is one to one or that it is a bijection and onto?

Note that a function is a bijection, injection, or surjection. So you wouldn't prove that the set $T$ is a bijection, but you prove it is countable by constructing an appropriate function and proving it is injective, surjective, or bijective respectively.

Comment: As long as one of those properities bijection,injection or surjection is proved that is enough to answer the question.

Comment: Depends on the set. An injection from $\mathbb{N} \to T$ is not sufficient, because you have only shown $|\mathbb{N}| \leq |T|$ and $\mathbb{R}$ certainly satisfies this. However, providing a surjection from $T \to \mathbb{N}$ would be sufficient. A bijection shows two sets have the same cardinality.

Answer (score 1):

As a simpler problem, consider how you would show that the integers 
$$\{\ldots -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3,\ldots\}$$
are denumerable.

One possible mapping sends non-negative numbers to odd numbers and negative numbers to even numbers.
$$\begin{align*}
\mathbb{Z}&\leftrightarrow \mathbb{N}\\
0&\leftrightarrow 1\\
1 &\leftrightarrow 3\\
2 &\leftrightarrow 5\\
3 &\leftrightarrow 7\\
4 &\leftrightarrow 9\\
 &\;\;\vdots\\
-1 &\leftrightarrow 2\\
-2 &\leftrightarrow 4\\
-3 &\leftrightarrow 6\\
-4 &\leftrightarrow 8\\
&\;\;\vdots
\end{align*}$$

Then the "divide-by-three" map shows that the set of integer multiples of 3 are the same size as the set of integers.

$$\begin{align*}
3\mathbb{Z}&\leftrightarrow \mathbb{Z}\\
0&\leftrightarrow 0\\
3 &\leftrightarrow 1\\
6 &\leftrightarrow 2\\
9 &\leftrightarrow 3\\
12 &\leftrightarrow 4\\
 &\;\;\vdots\\
-3 &\leftrightarrow -1\\
-6 &\leftrightarrow -2\\
-9 &\leftrightarrow -3\\
-12 &\leftrightarrow -4\\
&\;\;\vdots
\end{align*}$$

If you put these two maps together, you can get a map $3\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}\leftrightarrow \mathbb{N}$, which shows that the set of multiples of 3 is denumerable. $\square$